# Laplace Transform: Indeterminate Form in Definite Integral Change of Variables Calculation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, laplace-transform, change-of-variable, indeterminate-forms

I was trying to find the Laplace transform of $e^{3t}$:

$$\int^\infty_0 e^{3t}e^{-st} \ dt = \int_0^\infty e^{3t - st} \ dt = \lim_{x \to \infty}\int_0^x e^{3t - st} \ dt$$

So if we then attempt to solve this using change of variables instead of integration by parts, and we change the bounds of integration by making the substitution $t = 0$ and $t = x$, then we get $u = 0$ and $u = 3x - sx$ as the new bounds. But we then get

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{3 - s} \int_0^{3x - sx} e^u \ du = \dfrac{1}{3 - s} [(\infty - \infty) - 1],$$

which is an indeterminate form.

The solution should be $\dfrac{1}{s - 3}$.

What's going on here? Have I made an error?

I would appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: In the first line, do we agree that it isn't $3^{3t}$ but $e^{3t}$ ? ...

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for that. Fixed it.

Comment: Make a change of variable that gives you $e^{-u}$ instead of $e^{u}$ under the integration sign.

Comment: @JeanMarie If we do the change of variable $-u = 3t - st \Rightarrow u = st - 3t$, then we get $\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{s - 3} \int_0^{sx - 3x} e^{-u} \ du$, which gets us the same thing as before after another change of variable, no?

Comment: see my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S=s-3$.

Change of variables $u=(s-3)t=St$ which implies

$$du=S dt \iff dt=\frac{1}{S}du$$

permits to write the integral under the form :

$$\int_{u=0}^{u=+\infty} e^{-u}\frac{1}{S}du$$

whence the result : $\frac{1}{S}$

Answer (score 1):

In fact we have $$\int_0^x e^{3t - st} \ dt={1\over 3-s}e^{(3-s)t}\Bigg|_{0}^{\infty}={1\over 3-s}\Big(e^{(3-s)\infty}-1\Big)$$which is convergent only when $\Re(s-3)>0\iff \Re(s)>3$ i.e. $s$ falls within **ROC (Region of Convergence)**. In that case the answer would be $1\over s-3$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. First of all, how did you deduce that it converges only when $\Re(s-3)>0\iff \Re(s)>3$? And so it falls within the region of convergence, but converges to what? In other words, how do we get from ${1\over 3-s}\Big(e^{(3-s)\infty}-1\Big)$ to $\dfrac{1}{s - 3}$?

Comment: Your welcome. I'll show with some examples. First let $s=-1+10i$. Therefore$$\exp((3-s)\infty)=\exp((4-10i)\infty)=\exp(4\infty)\cdot \exp(-10i\cdot\infty)\to \text{diverges}$$<br><br> Second let $S=3-5i$ then we have$$\exp((3-s)\infty)=\exp(5i\cdot\infty)\to\text{diverges either}$$<br><br>and third and last define $s=5+7i$ which leads to $$\exp((3-s)\infty)=\exp(-2\infty-7i\cdot\infty)=0$$therefore in case $$\exp((3-s)\infty)$$ converges, it converges to $0$.

Comment: Perhaps It is because I haven't studied complex analysis, but It is not clear to me how they diverge/converge.

Comment: You can simply consider the real and imaginary parts of $\exp((3-s)t)$ for $t\to \infty$ and define $u=s-3=r+ix$ where $r,x\in \Bbb R$. Now, what happens when $e^{-rt}\cos xt$  and $e^{-rt}\sin xt$  when $r>=<0$?

Comment: I think you are discussing convergence/divergence concepts from complex analysis, which I am not familiar with. Whether or not a complex number diverges or converges is unknown to me, since I have only studied such things in the context of real analysis.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align} \int^\infty_0 e^{3t}e^{-st} \ dt &= \int_0^\infty e^{3t - st} \ dt \\ &= \lim_{c \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{3 - s} \int_0^{c(3 - s)} e^u \ du \\ &= \lim_{c \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{3 - s} \left[ e^{c(3 - s)} - 1 \right] \\ &= \lim_{c \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{3 - s} \left[ e^{c(3 - (x + iy))} - 1 \right] \\ &= \lim_{c \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{3 - s} \left[ e^{c((3 - x) - iy))} - 1 \right] \\ &= \lim_{c \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{3 - s} \left[ e^{c(3 - x)} e^{-ciy} - 1 \right] \\ &= \lim_{c \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{3 - s} \left[ \dfrac{e^{c(3 - x)}}{e^{ciy}} - 1 \right] \\ &= \lim_{c \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{3 - s} \left[ \dfrac{e^{3c}e^{-cx}}{e^{ciy}} - 1 \right] \\ &= \lim_{c \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{3 - s} \left[ \dfrac{e^{3c}}{e^{ciy}e^{cx}} - 1 \right], \end{align}$$

which only converges when $x > 3$, since we then get $\lim_{c \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{3 - s} \left[ \dfrac{e^{cx}}{e^{ciy}} - 1 \right]$, and $e^{ciy}$ (Euler's formula) is bounded.

So the final result is $\dfrac{1}{3 - s} \left[ 0 - 1 \right] = -\dfrac{1}{3 - s} = \dfrac{1}{s - 3}$, as required.